# Filtering fields from a PostgresSQL/PostGIS database layer in QGIS by Query builder

Tags: postgresql, qgis-3, query, filter

I incurring in an error while trying to make the following filter of fields in the layer properties Query builder in QGIS 3 from a PostGIS database.

`select "field_A", "field_B2", "field_D" from my_database`

what should be the correct sentence to filter fields in the Query builder?

Comment: that's a select of columns - you only need to use "field_A" = 'value'

Comment: The issue is that I have inherited a database with more than 200 fields -I know it's crazy- and I just need to pick 6 or 8 fields... Is there a way to solve it at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can hide columns using Query builder since what you add there is what comes after `select * from table where`... which will select rows.

But you can create a [virtual layer](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/virtual_layers.html):

- Add the non-filtered layer to the map
- Go to Layer - Create Layer - New Virtual Layer
- Add your query

[image]